# Joining development NPM dependencies into single meta-package

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

Is there a way to create a meta-package, which `package.json`:

**a)** contains a list of dependencies, which are not used to build this
    package;

**b)** enforces NPM to install these deps, when this very
    meta-package is added to the project, both for production for the development?

The problem is that I have a few dozens of packages (both, prod and dev) in my boilerplate, which I copy from project to project. I would like to have one private package, which once added to project's `package.json` tells npm which other prod and dev deps to install. I want to improve the process of using the boilerplate, because when I change something it it, I have (actually that is my will, not the enforcement) to make these changes in all the projects built on the base of this boilerplate and which are still in development.

I have managed to add all the deps I usually use to `production` section of my meta-package's `package.json`. However there are two problems with this approach:

**1.** A lot of unnecessary packages are installed when I build the meta-package (I have to build it as it contains some helpers in ES6/7);

**2.** I still have to copy/paste the list of production deps into every new project to provide NPM information, what to install on the production server.

Non-npm solutions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it appeared to be quite easy to do:

**1.** First of all, it is required to split all the packages used in the boilerplate into two groups - required to run the app (`production`), and required to build and debug (`development`).

**2.** Create the `production` meta-package (`meta-prod`). package.json content:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    < Here we have the list of production dependencies.       >
},
...
```

Compile it if necessary and push to git (i.e., github).

**3.** Create the `development` meta-package (`meta-dev`). package.json content:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    < Here we have the list of development dependencies.       >
    < Please note, that this is in the 'dependencies' section, >
    < not the 'devDependencies'.                               >
},
...
```

Push it to git.

**4.** Remove all the dependencies from the boilerplate's `package.json` and replace it with:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "meta-prod": "git+https://github.com/your_account/meta-prod"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "meta-dev": "git+https://github.com/your_account/meta-dev"
},
...
```

That's it! Dependencies will be installed when you do `npm install` and will be properly considered by `npm` as production and development. Now you can use much smaller `package.json` boilerplate and update the list of your devs from the single point.

The only downside is that `npm` does not catch the version change when you use package from `git`, so to update packages within the app you have to remove meta-packages directories from `node_modules` and rerun `npm install`. To fix this you can publish your package to npmjs.com (better to publish it as private package if you are the paid npm customer) and change meta-package version every time you update it.

Here is the boilerplate and meta-packages example:

- [app boilerplate](https://gitlab.com/priezz/meteor-react-hot)
- [meta-prod](https://gitlab.com/priezz/meteor-helpers)
- [meta-dev](https://gitlab.com/priezz/meteor-helpers-dev)

Comment: Will you be able to use the dependencies of dependencies? Isn't the point of NPM that each package has their own copy of dependencies (thus disallowing use of recursively installed dependencies)?

Comment: Since version 3 `npm` does package [flattening](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3) and install them all into the upper level `node_modules` directory until the sub-dependencies do not conflict with each other. So, yes, it is possible to use that approach to use sub-dependencies. Of course, the downside is that this is the implicit way to get them into your project.